# How to display default group icons in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I'm finding lots of discussion about how to replace the default group icons in an ExpandableListView, but I'm not coming up with anything on how to get the defaults to display in the first place.

The defaults (as shown [here](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/02/expandable-lists-and-check-boxes.html), if that's what they look like [new to Android, this is my first ExpandableListView]) will be fine with me, if I can get them to show.

[image: ExpandableListView]

I'm using the sample code from the article; I have no need for the embedded CheckBoxes at this time.

Any assistance is appreciated.

**--EDIT--**

Also, does anyone have any theories as to why the default icons show in the article (again, if that's what they look like--if someone could confirm that'd be great) but don't show for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using custom layouts for your group rows the default icons are overridden by your layout.  You'll need to add them to your layout in order for them to display.

Comment: Ah, this sounds like the ticket. I don't need anything but basic text in my group/child rows, so this shouldn't be difficult. Do you have/know of any sample code for adding text rows that doesn't use custom layouts?

Comment: Regarding your custom layout tip, I'm trying [this code](http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html) but the default icons still don't show (I'm still not sure what they're supposed to look like), even though the code doesn't appear to be using any custom layouts. Any ideas?

Comment: Searching through the styles that come with the emulator is always a fantastic way to start looking for UI stuff.  I found that on ExpandableListView there is an `android:groupIndicator` value that you can set.  By default it is set to `@android:drawable/expander_group` so you may try that.

Comment: It looks like a bug in the QVGA Emulator, which I found [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7975) when searching on your `android:groupIndicator` tip. I switched to HVGA and the default icon displays just fine. So thanks for accidentally pointing me in the right direction! :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can changed default icon with your own icon as below.

```
android:groupIndicator="@drawable/image"
```

Comment: anks, but I don't want to change the default icon. I want to get it to show in the first place. Do you know how to do that?